# Variable bullPostion is not being seen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I have 2 variables specifically called "cowPosition" and "bullPosition" however its not being seen inside the function

Here is a snippet of my code

```py
cowPosition = 1
bullPosition = 1

def gameplay():
    setposition(True) # Sets the starting position for both bull and cow
    while cowPosition or bullPosition >= 25:
        bullPosition += 1
        print(bullPosition)
```

What I want it too do is that it will loop 25 times until bullPosition = 25

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by "it is not being seen inside the function"? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I suggest you learn about variable scope. Most likely you should initialize the variables inside the `gameplay()` function instead of globally.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice All I currently want it to do is so it will loop until bullPosition >= 25

I will have a read on variable scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution is to declare local variables rather than global ones:

```
def gameplay():
    cowPosition = 1
    bullPosition = 1
    while cowPosition or bullPosition >= 25:
        bullPosition += 1
        print(bullPosition)
```

To understand how this works, I suggest you read about the difference between local and global scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something fundamental about Python variable scopes. Both `cowPosition` and `bullPosition` are a part of what is known as the *global space*. The `gameplay` method is not allowed to modify that variable because both `cowPosition` and `bullPosition` are not within `gameplay`'s *local scope*.

While you can do this:

```
my_variable = 1

def my_func():
    print(my_variable) # print does not modify my_variable
```

You are attempting to *modify* the value of `bullPosition` with this line:

```
bullPosition += 1
```

You **cannot** change the value of that variable unless you specify so, using the `global` keyword. For example, you cannot do:

```
my_variable = 1

def my_func():
    my_variable += 1 # this expression would modify my_variable
```

Which throws:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_variable' referenced before assignment

```
def my_func():
    global my_variable # specify that you want to modify variable

    my_variable += 5
    my_variable = my_variable + 1
```

## Warning

While using `global` seems like a magic fix, the use of it is generally discouraged, especially in larger programs. The reasoning for this is that you can end up mutating (changing the value ***and/or*** type) of global variables accidentally. You can imagine how difficult a bug like this would be to track down if you had functions that used the `global` keyword to mutate the variable. Instead, you might pass them as parameters:

```
gameplay(cowPosition, bullPosition):
    ...

gameplay(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the problems you have made:

1. The variables should be inside the function
2. You have put the wrong operator in the while loop it should be < not >= otherwise it would become a forever loop
3. In the while loop you have put an or statement so even if bullPosition is 25 it will still run because cowPosition is not 25(it is not an error if you want it to be like that)

Final code:

```python
def gameplay():
    cowPosition = 1
    bullPosition = 1
    while cowPosition or bullPosition < 25:
        bullPosition += 1
        print(bullPosition)
```

If you want to use the variables outside the function just make them global as shown below:

```python
def gameplay():
    global cowPosition = 1
    global bullPosition = 1
    while cowPosition or bullPosition < 25:
        bullPosition += 1
        print(bullPosition)
```